# How to print contents of va_list in ansi c

Tags: c, variadic-functions, ansi-c

I am trying to print the contents of a va_list,
I want to pass an array to it
I am getting gibrish in return

```
int printVA(int num_args,...);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int numArgs = 3;
    int arr [3];
    arr[0]=183;
    arr[1]=184;
    arr[2]=15;
    printVA(numArgs,arr);

    return 0;
}




int printVA(int num_args,...){
    va_list arg_list;
    int my_arg;
    va_start(arg_list, num_args);

    for(int i = 0; i<num_args;i++){
        my_arg = va_arg(arg_list, int);
        printf("%d\n", my_arg);
    }
    va_end(arg_list);
    return 1;

}
```

this is what i get

```
1606416584
15
1606416584
```

Comment: Read up on how C passes arrays.

Comment: If you want to be able to call your function either with variable arguments or an array, write two functions, like `execl` and `execv`. The version with variable arguments can simply collect them into an array and call the array version.

Comment: @Barmar ... or at least can perform the same operation as the other, as using an intermediate array might be inappropriate, depending on the platform used (e. g. µC with limited stack space).

Comment: @Barmar the reason i even asked this question, it may be an error by my part, but i compared this va list to the java va list, where you can pass either a list of arguments like this arg1,arg2,arg3 or an array containing the argmuents, and there is no need for a second function with an array declaration in it, it works just fine

Comment: C doesn't have an "apply" feature. You can't turn an array into a variable-length argument list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling it incorrectly, pass the arguments themselves, not an array of them:

```
printVA(numArgs, arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
```

or simply:

```
printVA(numArgs, 183, 184, 15);
```

On the other hand, if you really want to pass the array, `va_list` is not the right solution.